# tomcat and dynamic dns

Tags: tomcat, ssl, dns, remote-server

I configured a dynamic DNS with no-ip.com. I have on my remote machine a Tomcat Application server. I also configured a Virtual Server on the router both on 8080 and 8443 ports and I edited "server.xml" to work with SSL. Typing http://localhost:8080 and https://localhost:8443 everything works fine. On another machine if I type http://mydomainname.noipdomainname:8080 it works, but if I type **https://mydomainname.noipdomainname:8443** it **doesn't works**.

Please help me configuring the server!

In addition: the error is  111(net::ERR_TUNNEL_CONNECTION_FAILED)

Answer (score 0):

We have had something similar happen to our customers who are going through proxys, you don't mention which browser but does this help?

https://support.servertastic.com/entries/21464176-error-111-net-err-tunnel-connection-failed-unknown-error